# Adding a Webreference from c#

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-reference

I am trying to access a webserver from a c# client. I have added the webreference in the C# client .
When i call the API i get the following exception

```
"SOAPException was unhanded"
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.dotv.server.api.soap.DimService.setUser(java.lang.String)
```

any clue whats wrong here?

The code:

```
     WebReference.SLVDimmingServiceService service;
     service = new WebReference.SLVDimmingServiceService();
     service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "password");
     service.setDimmingLevel("SC", "olc_7050_2.OLC[0]", (float)100.00);
```

---

The exception:

---

---

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.dotv.streetlightserver.api.soap.SLVDimmingService.setUser(java.lang.String)

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

at WindowsFormsApplication4.WebReference.SLVDimmingServiceService.setDimmingLevel(String controllerStrId, String idOnController, Single dimmingLevel) in C:\Users\310103448\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testproject\WindowsFormsApplication4\Web References\WebReference\Reference.cs:line 254

### at WindowsFormsApplication4.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\310103448\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testproject\WindowsFormsApplication4\Form1.cs:line 42

### OK

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the error.  Put the code in a try catch and get a detailed error message?

Comment: Posted the code and exception Fred .